# R no me deja cambiar la ruta donde se instalan los paquetes

Tags: rstudio

Los paquetes de Rstudios no se me estaban descargando, por lo que busque porque pasaba esto en internet y descubrí que es porque los paquetes se están instalando en una carpeta que R no lee o algo así. No se como cambiar esta ruta y tampoco cual es el problema exacto. No se nada de R necesito ayuda y en términos simples por favor.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170399/change-r-default-library-path-using-libpaths-in-rprofile-site-fails-to-work

Comment: La carpeta de instalación de paquetes por defecto no debería modificarse, eventualmente habría que ver por que no te deja instalar ahi. Tienes algún mensaje de error? edita tu pregunta y agrega esta información.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.